# Is there any way to wait for a Dom to be updated or asynchronously update the Dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, dom

I have a simple loading bar made with css, you update the css and the bar fills, super simple.
I decided to update the bar with jQuery, works great but now I throw it into a practical environment. I have a bunch of files being downloaded and each time a file successfully downloads, it updates the position. The main problem is that it downloads the files so fast, and places the files correctly fast enough that it just doesn't update the loading bar unless I set a timeout interval of 300-400ms..it does log into console and I made an interval function that continously checks to see if a file is finished based on a global variable. No matter where I place the function to update the loading bar or how I update it, it seems the Dom will not react unless there's a big enough delay between files OR it will react at the very end (jumps to 100).

**Is there any way to wait for a Dom to be updated by J's OR can you spot a problem in my code that causes this issue?**

I also tried promises too but it didn't change how the browser reacts to the function.

This is all being done inside a Cordova environment but I tested it on chrome too and it works as long as the pc is powerful enough it seems.

The file Transfer function has an "on Success" too but that doesn't do anything as the Dom wont update in it until after all the downloads are done OR there's a delay

My solutions so far is to either intentionally lag the downloader, or lag it every 10 or 20 files to update the position

Edit: here's my loading bar Js

```
  var colorInc = 100 / 3;
  function setWater(myval)
  {
   var val = myval;
var waitForMe = $.Deferred();
  if(val != ""
  && !isNaN(val)
  && val <= 100
  && val >= 0)
{
  setTimeout(function(){waitForMe.resolve()}, 100);
  var valOrig = val;
  val = 100 - val;

  if(valOrig == 0)
  {
    //$("#percent-box").val(0);
    $(".progress .percent").text(0 + "%");
  }
  else $(".progress .percent").text(valOrig + "%");

  $(".progress").parent().removeClass();
  $(".progress .water").css("top", val + "%");

  if(valOrig < colorInc * 1)
    $(".progress").parent().addClass("red");
  else if(valOrig < colorInc * 2)
    $(".progress").parent().addClass("orange");
  else
    $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
}
else
{
  setTimeout(function(){waitForMe.resolve()}, 100);
  $(".progress").parent().removeClass();
  $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
  $(".progress .water").css("top", 100 - 67 + "%");
  $(".progress .percent").text(67 + "%");
  //$("#percent-box").val("");
}
return waitForMe.promise();
   };
```

Dowload tracker:

```
 var DLProgress = null;
 function updateProgress() {
  var oldNum = 0;
  DLProgress = setInterval(function(){
    if(!doneArts) {
       doneArts = true;
   downloadHelper("Articles",articleSize,33.33,0);
   }else if(currPos >= totalSize - 1){
   clearInterval(DLProgress);
   goNews();
    currPos = 0;
   doneArticles = false;
    doneJson = false;
   doneArts = false;
   } else if(currPos >= articleSize && !doneArticles) {
    doneArticles = true;
   downloadHelper("json",jsonSize,33.33,33.33);
    } else if(currPos >= articleSize + jsonSize && !doneJson) {
    doneJson = true;
     downloadHelper("img",imgSize,33.33,66.66);
     }
      if(oldNum != currPos) {
      oldNum = currPos;
      setWater(Math.ceil(100 * currPos / totalSize));
     }
     },5);
    }
```

Download Helper :

```
 function downloadHelper(name,size,maxPerc,startingPoint) {
 dataFiles[name].forEach(function(file){
   var getItem = localStorage.getItem(name+"/"+file[0]) || null; //might not work
   if(getItem === null || getItem !== file[1]) {
   //download file.
    if(file[0] !== null && file[1] !== null) {
      //setWater(Math.ceil(100 * currPos / totalSize)).done(function(){downloader(name+"/"+file[0],file[1]);});
      setTimeout(function(){downloader(name+"/"+file[0],file[1])},window.dltime);
      window.dltime += 200;
    }
   }
  });
 };
```

File transfer used :
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

It Does update after each download helper has finished

**Is there any way to wait for a Dom to be updated by J's OR can you spot a problem in my code that causes this issue?**

Comment: The plugin is used to upload the file and you are talking about download. Are you facing issue of updating the progress bar for upload progress?

Comment: The plugin downloads files, yes I am facing issues updating the progress bar..it will only update when there is enough of a delay between each download.

Comment: Build a queue, process queue for few items at a time, show progress, process next items in queue an so on. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418399/3581139

Comment: I agree with @jeetaz. You need to have queue with files and hide your progress bar when queue is empty.

Comment: I don't see the variable currPos being set anywhere, except where you're setting it to 0.

Comment: `.parent()` is kind of slow, you might be flooding the CPU. Try caching the progress update selectors to improve perf, which might open up enough time to re-layout. you might also only update 5 times a second instead of once per file; just track the last update time, and compare to Date.now(), and return if <200...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM is updated each time the download is completed - it could be a problem.
We should separate upload progress and animation. When file is downloaded you should just change some kind of Model and use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Notes) recursively to animate a progress bar.

requestAnimationFrame is called `60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate, paused in most browsers when running in background tabs or hidden <iframe>s in order to improve performance and battery life.`

Comment: I will give this a shot and mark it as the answer while combining other solutions on here, I guess I'm over loading the Dom.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the case with the variable **currPos**. Use debug tool to mark the lines and inspect value of currPos. Somehow your code is managed to jump it 0 to articleSize.

Comment: It does work just fine when I give a big enough delay between each download.